# Why cant I install brightness-controller

Tags: brightness, webapps

I have been having problems with adjusting the brightness.....it is at max (when I look at it, it is at max in the settings. By the way, I cant control it at all with the keyboard combination.)

I have decided to install this app, but it just wont work.....

Can someone confirm if it works at all? Or if I should at all?

https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/brightness-controller/

Comment: You better search the solution for your laptop model. This software will not solve it.

Comment: Have you tried installing it manually from a terminal? sudo apt-get install brightness-controler. Or if it's installed but doesn't work, run it from a terminal and paste here the output.

Comment: For using brightness control on laptops, you need drivers for the specific laptop, especially for the special keys.

Answer (score 0):

Install [Brightness Controller](https://lordamit.github.io/Brightness/) with the following commands:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:apandada1/brightness-controller
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install brightness-controller
```

You can control brightness using its slider.

[image]
<sub>(source: [ubuntu.com](https://myapps.developer.ubuntu.com/dev/thumbnail/225x170/appmedia/2014/01/brightness-controller_mac2_1.png))</sub>